# AnacondaでMeCabを使う際、printで結果が表示されません

Tags: anaconda, mecab

初めまして
最近WindowsのパソコンにAnaconda及びMeCabをインストールしましたがいざjupyter notebookで以下のコードを実行しようとすると結果が出ません。

```
import MeCab
mecab = MeCab.Tagger()
print(mecab.parse("すもももももももものうち"))
```

コードの左隣の箱に実行が完了したサイン（数字）が出てき、エラーメッセージが表示されないため、根本的な原因がわかりません。
どのようにすれば結果が表示されるようになりますでしょうか？
sysやCommand Promptなどではcharset はUTF-8となっており、Command Promptではうまく実行できます。
インストールしたライブラリはMecabとmecab-python3だけです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `MeCab.Tagger()`のパラメータ指定をして(or 変えて)みるとか。[PythonとMeCabで形態素解析(on Windows)](https://qiita.com/menon/items/f041b7c46543f38f78f7), [PythonでMeCabを利用する方法を現役エンジニアが解説【初心者向け】](https://techacademy.jp/magazine/22052), [WindowsやmacやLinuxにpipでPython用MeCabバインディングをいれる](https://qiita.com/yukinoi/items/990b6933d9f21ba0fb43)

Comment: 参考までに、2年ほど前に issue として取り上げられていて [Jupyter Notebook is not showing the output of any code executed on the cell · Issue #11027](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11027)、原因の一つとして  antivirus ソフトウェアが挙げられています。